# Set js variable inside jquery append tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

i am using this code to add a marker to a google map using google maps api v3 and to open a dialog that a user can fill.

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function(event, map) {
    $(map).click(function(event) {
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
            'position': event.latLng,
            'draggable': true,
            'bounds': false
        }, function(map, marker) {
            $('#dialog').append('<form id="dialog' + marker.__gm_id + '" name="dialog" method="get" action="/" style="display:none;"><p><label for="country">Country</label><input id="country' + marker.__gm_id + '" class="txt" name="country" value=""/></p><p><label for="state">State</label><input id="state' + marker.__gm_id + '" class="txt" name="state" value=""/></p><p><label for="address">Address</label><input id="address' + marker.__gm_id + '" class="txt" name="address" value=""/></p><p><label for="comment">Comment</label><textarea id="comment' + marker.__gm_id + '" class="txt" name="comment" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea></p></form>');
            findLocation(marker.getPosition(), marker);
        }).dragend(function(event) {
            findLocation(event.latLng, this);
        }).click(function() {
            openDialog(this);
        });
    });
});
```

Every dialog form should be unique as '+marker.gm__id+' should be an unique identifier.

But '+marker.gm__id+' returns "undefined", so every form id is "dialogundefined".

i tried to define

```
var i = 0;
```

and change the append line to

```
$('#dialog').append('<form id="dialog'+i+'" name="dialog" method="get" action="/" style="display:none;"><p><label for="country">Country</label><input id="country'+i+'" class="txt" name="country" value=""/></p><p><label for="state">State</label><input id="state'+i+'" class="txt" name="state" value=""/></p><p><label for="address">Address</label><input id="address'+i+'" class="txt" name="address" value=""/></p><p><label for="comment">Comment</label><textarea id="comment'+i+'" class="txt" name="comment" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea></p></form>');
```

This doesn't work; The dialog isn't shown any more.
my target is to have unique form identifiers f.e. "dialog1", "dialog2" and so on.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `var i = 0` outside the scope of the function, and increment it by 1 every single time a new dialog is appended:

```
var i = 0;
$('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function(event, map) {
    $(map).click(function(event) {
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
            'position': event.latLng,
            'draggable': true,
            'bounds': false
        }, function(map, marker) {
            $('#dialog').append('<form id="dialog' + i + '" name="dialog" method="get" action="/" style="display:none;"><p><label for="country">Country</label><input id="country' + i + '" class="txt" name="country" value=""/></p><p><label for="state">State</label><input id="state' + i + '" class="txt" name="state" value=""/></p><p><label for="address">Address</label><input id="address' + i + '" class="txt" name="address" value=""/></p><p><label for="comment">Comment</label><textarea id="comment' + i + '" class="txt" name="comment" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea></p></form>');
            findLocation(marker.getPosition(), marker);
            i++;
        }).dragend(function(event) {
            findLocation(event.latLng, this);
        }).click(function() {
            openDialog(this);
        });
    });
});
```